# How to cast Manifest files via Chromecast sdk?

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast

How to cast manifest file?
i try to create media information like this:

```
let customData = NSMutableDictionary()
        customData[CONTENT_ID_KEY] = contentData.contentID
        customData[CONTENT_TYPE_KEY] = Int(getMediaType(contentData).rawValue)

        let mediaInformation = GCKMediaInformation(contentID: contentData.contentID, streamType: GCKMediaStreamType.buffered, contentType: "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml", metadata: metaData, streamDuration: 0, mediaTracks: nil, textTrackStyle: GCKMediaTextTrackStyle.createDefault(), customData: customData)
```

And then i try to start casting:

```
let castSession = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentCastSession
castSession.remoteMediaClient?.loadMedia(mediaInformation, autoplay: true, playPosition: 0)
```

And chromecast starts loading but after few seconds it stopps. What might be the issue?﻿

Comment: Have you looked at the logs on the receiver?

Comment: if you mean GCKLogger, it returns nothing

Comment: No, I mean the receiver, your application running on the cast device. Checkout the section on debugging on our cast developers site and connect your chrome debugger, turn on the logging and see what error you get there. For this you'd need to have either a Styled or a custom receiver.